# Display month and date in highcharts categories

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

i am trying to create a highchart, i'm  using this firat time, i have some categories  something like:

```
Categories = ["2015-10-31", "2015-10-30", "2015-11-09", "2015-11-08", "2015-11-07", "2015-11-06", "2015-11-10", "2015-11-05", "2015-11-04", "2015-11-12", "2015-11-03", "2015-11-11", "2015-11-02", "2015-11-01", "2015-11-13"]
```

I need to plot categories like :

**31 oct, 30 oct 09 nov, 08Nov 07Nov 06Nov** some thing like this

How can i achieve this?

Comment: Have you tried anything? If so, please post a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Create a month array,do a foreach loop on the categories,slice the date and replace month with the name from the month array

try

```
   var months = ['Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec'];

    Categories=    ["2015-10-31", "2015-10-30", "2015-11-09", "2015-11-08", "2015-11-07", "2015-11-06", "2015-11-10", "2015-11-05", "2015-11-04", "2015-11-12", "2015-11-03", "2015-11-11", "2015-11-02", "2015-11-01", "2015-11-13"]
    newcat =[];
    $.each(Categories,function(i,v){
     newcat.push(v.slice(-2)+months[parseInt(v.slice(5,8)+1)]);
    });
```

then in your char replace Categories with newcat

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/e2bm7wu8/4/

Comment: i need month  then date   like nov31 dec23

Comment: Month is not displying proper  its displaying wrong

Comment: yes i tried   please  chekc in you js fiddle also   2015-10-31    displaying nov 31 but it is oct 31

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95038/discussion-between-shakti-sharma-and-madalin-ivascu).